# Display going to "no signal" at strange times

Tags: windows, display, gpu

I know enough to assume this is a video card issue. I am using an AMD Radeon HD 6800 card that has worked like a charm. Recently, while playing League of Legends, this happened. The screen went completely black, reported no signal, and a loud "skipping" noise played from the speakers (assuming that means the computer froze up behind the blank monitor).

Trying to diagnose this issue, I downloaded GPU-Z. Then, once when running GPU-Z, it did this same exact thing: no signal, computer "froze." The video card's fan continues running. The computer remains on and seems fully functional. The temperature of the GPU is completely normal.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade your graphics card recently or add any other new hardware that might draw more power?

I had a problem similar to that. It was caused because the power supply was not large enough to support the graphics card.  In that case it works just fine until you start doing heavy graphics and power consumption on the GPU goes up, it'll then cut out, because the power supply can't put out enough amps.

Comment: I thought it could also be the power supply, but then it doesn't make sense that it could be the case when this occurs when I launch GPU-Z. Launching that application shows no spike in GPU usage or anything.

Comment: Is it a new card? I really think power is the most likely culprit. If you have access to a bigger power supply or can borrow one, I'd try to swap it out and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I'd agree it's probably a power problem, based on multiple similar experiences, but one time just updating my GPU drivers solved everything. Try that first if you haven't.